# iOS create date from string

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I make this format in iOS: "Mon Jan 26 07:57:33 +0000 2015"?

I have tried this

```
NSString *createdAt=@"Mon Jan 26 07:57:33 +0000 2015";
NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy"];
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[formatter setTimeZone:gmt];
NSDate *date=[formatter dateFromString:createdAt];
```

but this returns me nil always

Comment: What is your input date?

Comment: You've got `ddd` at the start?

Comment: createdAt contains string Mon Jan 26 07:57:33 +0000 2015

Comment: Also you shouldn't be setting the timezone as that is accounted for in the date format?

Comment: You get nil because your formatter does not correspond to your string.

Comment: @Hamza then whats the correct formatter for this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Convert string to date 
//Fri, 23 Jan 2015 14:24:24 IST

```
    NSString *beginString = [currentFields objectForKey:@"pubDate"];
    dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"]];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/Kiev"]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];
    dateFromString = [dateFormat dateFromString:beginString];
```

This is my example. Your date formatter should be the same as your original string date.